# Add options and angular directive to accordion code

Tags: angularjs

I created a simple Angular accordion as follows [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/dYOzJj):

```
<dl accordion>
  <dt class="link">dt 01</dt>
  <dd class="body">dd 01</dd>
  <dt class="link">dt 02</dt>
  <dd class="body">dd 02</dd>
</dl>
```

I used a definition list but could use any other syntax.

And I created a Angular directive as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
}).directive('accordion', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',    
    link: function(scope, element) {     
      element.children('.body').hide();
      element.children('.link').bind('click', function(event)  {              
      $(this).toggleClass('active');         
      //$(this).parent().children('.body').hide();
       $(this).next('.body').toggle().toggleClass('active');                        
    });
   }
  };
});
```

This is working but I would like to make a few changes:

Being able to define if opening one item closes the other.

Being able to use angular directive instead of classes:

```
<dl accordion>
  <dt accordion-link>dt 01</dt>
  <dd accordion-body>dd 01</dd>
  <dt accordion-link>dt 02</dt>
  <dd accordion-body>dd 02</dd>
</dl>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You might consider looking at how other available accordion modules/directives are written. Current question is too broad. Narrowing down some specifics would help also

Comment: Example of existing accordion would be angular-ui-bootstrap accordion